# TCL Regular Expression

Tags: regex, tcl

I have two types of interfaces "Ethernet9/12/1 and Ethernet8/34".  I wanted to parse both type of interfaces using single regular expression.

I was trying to achieve this in the below manner:

```
set int "Ethernet9/12/1"
regexp -nocase "(.*t)((\\d+)\/(\\d+)/\(\\d+))" $int - int_type int_num mod_num port broken_port
puts $int_type
puts $int_num
puts $mod_num
puts $port
puts $broken_port
```

This code works for Ethernet9/12/1.  But, the same regexp does not work for Ethernet8/34.  I need help to achieve this in the single regexp using TCL.

Kindly help.

Comment: Try it with: "(.*t)((\d+)/(\d+)(/\d+)*)"

Comment: set int "Ethernet91/12/2"

regexp -nocase "(.*t)((\\d+)\/(\\d+)\/(\\d+))" $int - int_type int_num mod_num port broken_port
puts $int_type
puts $int_num
puts $mod_num
puts $port
puts $broken_port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the last part optional with a non-capturing group:

```
regexp -nocase "(.*t)((\\d+)\/(\\d+)(?:/(\\d+))?)" $int - int_type int_num mod_num port broken_port
                                    ^^^       ^^
```

See [IDEONE Tcl demo](http://ideone.com/J4v0qD)

Output:

```
Ethernet
8/34
8
34
```

A non-capturing group is only meant to group subpatterns and does not interfere with the capturing groups you already defined to be used later.

Comment: Thank you R Nar and Wiktor.  Your solution helped me.  Do you have any reference materia/web site pointers, which will teach me about regexp optional part and other advanced regexp contents.

Comment: Actually, optional in regex means matching something 1 or 0 times. This a basic thing, a `?` quantifier. See [this quantifier cheatsheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet). To match an  optional digit after a sequence of letters, one would use `[a-zA-Z]+\d?`. Here is a nice article on optional regex patterns: [*`Optional Items`* at *regular-expressions.info*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just make the second part optional with `?`:

```
(.*t)((\d+)\/(\d+)(?:\/(\d+))?)
```

Tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wU9pH6/1)

NOTE: I escaped your `/` characters with a `\` but that might flavor specific.

Answer (score 0):

The code becomes a lot more manageable if one doesn't concentrate all processing within the regular expressions.

```
set int Ethernet9/12/1

regexp -nocase {(.+t)(.*)} $int -> int_type int_num
lassign [split $int_num /] mod_num port broken_port

puts [list $int_type $int_num $mod_num $port $broken_port]
# -> Ethernet 9/12/1 9 12 1

set int Ethernet8/34

regexp -nocase {(.+t)(.*)} $int -> int_type int_num
lassign [split $int_num /] mod_num port broken_port

puts [list $int_type $int_num $mod_num $port $broken_port]
# -> Ethernet 8/34 8 34 {}
```

Documentation:
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)